# Problem with increasing Java heap size in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I have a problem with error saying `ERROR:  'Java heap space'`. I followed [these instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?) to increase the heap size for Eclipse, but it doesn't work. Eclipse seems to be ignoring the given values. My `eclipse.ini` file looks like this:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.ecli
pse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

The Eclipse version is 3.6.1 running on Mac.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: When exactly do you see this message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure you are configuring parameters for your application execution and not for Eclipse itself?

I usually configure heap size in the Run | Run Configuration dialog.

Answer (score 6):

Try to supply -vmargs directly to Eclipse executable instead of ***eclipse.ini*** file.

```
eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx730m
```

There is a bug in Eclipse, that prevents it from supplying "vmargs" clause of ***eclipse.ini*** to JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Humm... -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1024m all looking fine. When are you having this error? 
At Startup? Can you try switching JVM or downloading the 32 bit version? 
When building? Try this guide to give ANT more memory: http://ericfickes.com/2008/10/osx-flexbuilder-java-heap-space-error/
On the App Server / Servlet Container? Increase it's heapsize and permgen space.

Comment: Nope, not at start time. I'm creating many objects and handling them, it's taking a lot of space. That's why I increased the size. But i'm using a profiler and it doesn't say that the heap size is increased.

Comment: In a application that you are running inside eclipse or eclipse itself? If you mean the first, then you need to go into Running Configurations / [Your Running Configuration] / Arguments Tab / VM Arguments and set it here.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse.ini is for eclipse itself not for running applications. For that use a run configuration to set the start parameters.

One more note: java on MacOSX doesn't have the XX:MaxPermSize or any another XX flags.

Answer (score 0):

To those who get the same error under Eclipse, try to restore cache files (if they were removed accidentally in WAR folder ), this way I solve the same problem under my Eclipse' project. note: I don't think there is a link between Memory allowed to Eclipse and memory for App.